# Perforce command to retrieve changelists affecting specific files

Tags: perforce

I am trying to find all `.properties` files that have been touched since a specific date (last release) so the i18n team can localize any modified/new strings. I am using the following command:

```
p4 changes @2015/11/01,@now //depot/cloud/sp-main/ui/....properties
```

However, when I run it like this, I get changes all they way back to 2013, though they do contain only changes that have modified `.properties` files

If I run

```
p4 changes //depot/cloud/sp-main/ui/....properties  @2015/11/01,@now
```

Then I get changes since 2015/11/01 but it gives me changes that do not contain `.properties` files.

How can I combine the filespec with the @date?

**Reference:**

- [p4 changes](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r14.2/manuals/p4guide/chapter.files.html#files.changelist.display)
- [filespec](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/filespecs.html)

Comment: The problem is the space between the file pattern and the date specification. Those two things must be combined into a single argument without a space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

```
p4 changes //depot/cloud/sp-main/ui/....properties@2015/11/01,@now
```

The file spec contains both the file path and the revision specification. (See `p4 help revisions` for the latter.)